# Affdex SDK: which face will be captured when there are multiple faces in the camera view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, affdex-sdk

I am trying to analyze the emotion data using the affdex sdk integration in my Unity game.
Below is the piece of code that I am using to get the emotions from face.

```
public float currentJoy;
public override void onImageResults(Dictionary<int, Face> faces)
{
    if (faces.Count > 0)
    {
        // get emotions
        faces[0].Emotions.TryGetValue(Emotions.Joy, out currentJoy);
        // similarly get other emotions
    }
}
```

Usually, there is only one face in front of the camera, but often it happens that there is another smaller face in the camera view. For example, consider the following picture.

[image]

If something similar happens while recording emotions, a main face in front of the camera and a smaller face somewhere behind. `faces.Count` would be greater than 1 in such a case. Would `faces[0]` still refer to the main face in front of the camera, or will be be random. For me there is no way to verify it myself, since I can't really say with certainty that whose emotions are being captured.

Comment: You should ask this [here](https://www.affectiva.com/contact-us/) if you can't find out testing it, how should we know how this SDK was implemented? Simply get a very happy and a very sad face, switch positions, move around and watch what happens to your indexes I guess ;)

Comment: Yes, I have asked them as well. but they also suggested to put it here with the affdex tag in it, so I did, along with posting in their forum.

Comment: As it is a Dictionary I would expect the same as you: The SDK tries to match recognized faces to already known ones and keeps their indices. But who knows how they did it, though ;)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will wait to hear back from them.